# Why to care about local uniform convergence of characteristic function in proving multivariate CLT?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_{1},X_{2}, \dots \sim_{i.i.d.}$ some Borel probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$; let $\mathbb{E}X_{1} \equiv m$; let $\text{var} X_{1} \equiv V$. Then it can be shown that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_{n} - m)$ converges in distribution to multivariate normal with mean $0$ and variance $V$. After utilizing the i.i.d. univariate CLT, it can be shown that the characteristic function $\varphi_{n}(t)$ of the random variable $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_{n} - m)$ converges pointwise to $\exp (-t'Vt/2)$, i.e. to the characteristic function of the multivariate normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $V$. Is not it true that we already obtained what we want so far? But why is it the case that a (typical?) proof of this result cares to use the fact that the function $t \mapsto \exp (-t'Vt/2)$ is continuous at $0$ so as to obtain the uniform convergence of $\varphi_{n}$ on some open ball of center $0$?

Comment: We want uniform convergence because pointwise convergence is not strong enough to ensure that the inverse of the ch.f., which requires integration to find, converges to the multivariate normal distribution, but uniform convergence is.